# What's the difference between using the constructor in VS Testing framework vs. TestInitialize() attribute?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing

Quick question, I'm using the Visual Studio's testing framework for unit testing. Just wondering what's the difference between using the constructor to do initialization work vs. having a method with [TestInitialize()] attribute?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do you use TestInitialize or the test class constructor to prepare each test? and why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/334515/do-you-use-testinitialize-or-the-test-class-constructor-to-prepare-each-test-and)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[This post](https://web.archive.org/web/20150323033456/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nnaderi/archive/2007/02/17/explaining-execution-order.aspx) gives an overview of the different methods. As you can see, the ctor is called immediately before the `ClassInitialize` (only once, of course) and `TestInitialize`.

So put stuff that requires code in `ClassInitialize` in your `TestInitialize` method. Everything that should be set up before `ClassInitialize` goes in the ctor.

Obviously, `TestInitialize` content will be executed once before each test. The corresponding method to close after each test is `TestCleanup`. For classes, use `ClassCleanup`. The same thing exists for assemblies as well (`AssemblyInitialize/Cleanup`).

[Further reading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/ms245248(v=vs.120))

Comment: Your first two sentences are incorrect. The ctor is called before each test (which gets its own instance). `ClassInitialize` is called (once) before any ctor (and hence any test) - this is why it has to be static!

Answer (score 9):

Conceptually they are they same, as MSTest creates a new instance of your test class before each test execution. However, technically there are a few differences:

1. The ctor is called before `TestInitialize` (no surprise as the latter is an instance method).
2. You have access to `TestContext` in `TestInitialize`.
3. More inheritance scenarios are enabled with `TestInitialize`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8689398/67824.
4. You can assign `readonly` fields in the ctor. I think it's pretty important: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45270180/67824.

Answer (score 2):

The `ctor` is for initializing the object.

`TestInitialize` is for initializing any objects or data needed to run the test.

Comment: But given that the object you're constructing is a test class, surely the only thing you would be initialising in that constructor are objects or data needed to run the test...

Comment: To clarify, TestInitialize runs before each test, so if you initialize objects here, they'll be re-created for each test.  This is good practice.  Otherwise, the same object would be shared in all tests in the class, a big no-no in unit testing.