# How to get test initialize in memory and use in each test

Tags: c#, performance, unit-testing

I'm trying to create Unit Test. I have class User:

```
 public class User
{
    public int UsersCount
    {
        get
        {
            using (MainContext context = new MainContext())
            {
                return context.Users.Count();
            }
        }
    }
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public Contact UserContact { get; set; }
}
```

My first test is UsersCount_Test test which tests UsersCount property:

```
 [TestMethod]
    public void UsersCount_Test()
    {
        var user = new User();
        var context = new MainContext();
        int usersCount = context.Users.Count();
        context.Users.Add(new User());
        context.SaveChanges();
        Assert.AreEqual(usersCount + 1, user.UsersCount, $"It should be {usersCount + 1} because we're adding one more user");
    }
```

If I add new test method in my test class (I'm using separate classes for testing each entity), I need to create new instance of User. That's why I did this:

```
    public class BaseTest<T>
{
    public T TestEntity;

    public MainContext TestContext = new MainContext();
}
```

Now each test classes inherits from this class. And also I created test initializer method. Now my test class looks like this   :

```
 [TestClass]
public class UserTest : BaseTest<User>
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void UsersCount()
    {
        int usersCount = TestContext.Users.Count();
        TestContext.Users.Add(new User());
        TestContext.SaveChanges();
        Assert.AreEqual(usersCount + 1, TestEntity.UsersCount, $"It should be {usersCount + 1} because we're adding one more user");
    }

    [TestInitialize]
    public void SetTestEntity()
    {
        TestEntity = new User();
    }
}
```

Now I'm adding new property to User and writing some logic:

```
  string phoneNumber;
    public string PhoneNumber { get { return phoneNumber; } set { SetUserContact(phoneNumber, value); phoneNumber = value; } }

    void SetUserContact(string oldContact, string newContact)
    {
        UserContact.ContactsList.Remove(oldContact);
        UserContact.ContactsList.Add(newContact);
    }
```

After that I'm creating new test :

```
     [TestMethod]
    public void ContactList_Test()
    {
        var newPhone = "+8888888888888";
        TestEntity.PhoneNumber = newPhone;
        Assert.IsTrue(TestEntity.UserContact.ContactsList.Any(a => a == newPhone), $"It should contains {newPhone}");
    }
```

Test fails because UserContact of TestEntity is null. I understood that TestEntity should be created by logic. After that I fix test initilizer method:

```
 [TestInitialize]
    public void SetTestEntity()
    {
        TestEntity = new User() { UserContact = new Contact() };
    }
```

Here is Contact model

```
    public class Contact
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    public virtual List<string> ContactsList { get; set; } = new List<string>();
}
```

My question is how to set TestEntity only one time, is it possible (maybe get it in memory and use it when it calls SetTestEntity method)? Because SetTestentity method creates a new entity in each test and it takes more development time. (For example, If creating an instance of UserContact takes 3 seconds all, test runs more than 3 seconds). Another way, in this case, is to set UserContact in ContactLists test, but I think it's not a good idea. In the future when we will add new logics, I need to fix each test. Please give me any suggestion and/or ideas.

Comment: if i understood correctly , you want to create entity object that last remain alive for your all test cases , right ?

Comment: @PranayRana I want to create entity by 'logic' (set all requirement properties, step by step,...) only one time and use it in all  test cases

Comment: then you should make use of builder pattern , that will build object for you based on your logic

Comment: @PranayRana Did you mean to create my own pattern, which helps to build object?

Comment: you can refer this : https://www.dofactory.com/net/builder-design-pattern  so i suggest just not follow it fully but create builder method that will build object for you or you can follow it full

Comment: @PranayRana it couldn't help. Its seems hard. By this way I need to build special object for each test

Comment: Couldn't you just create a base class DatabaseIntegrationTests with the TestInitialize method and derive your other test classes from that base class?

Comment: How can it help me?

Comment: @DIlshod I have a question about `UserContact`. Why it takes 3 seconds to initialize new instance of `UserContact`? The reason I ask it is quite simple; Although there is no clear definition of what is a `Unit test` there is a convention about some rules that UTs should be complaint with them: one of them is "fast execution" another one is "unit isolation". Fast execution is your problem but for me I feel that the source of your problem is with the "unit isolation"...

Comment: @Old Fox, It was just an example. I said that initialize new instance of UserContact may take 3 second. For example on ctor of UserContact class, I'm checking (or validating) is there any UserContact with this User, or I need to create UserContact  with some structure, for example by setting FirstName and LastName of User. And after setting FirstName or LastName there may be another logic. That's why I said that it can take 3 or more than 3 second. As you said, I think problem is with "fast execution"

Comment: @DIlshod initialize new instance + validate his properties shouldn't take more then a few nanoseconds/milliseconds unless something is problematic with the code... I know that your problem is with the fast execution but I'm trying to figure out the source of your problem.

Comment: @OldFox In my project, there are many BL codes which are executed step by step. In other words they work by structure. I think, it can more than 1,2 or even 3 second if BL code is BIG enough. For example in my structure when I create User and set UserContact validation of UserContact works and requires FirstName and LastName. If I set FirtName it changes FullName, when FullName changes it will begin to find UserContact with this FullName, After that if it find any result it check is those contact primary contact of another User.... So, I think it can take more than 1-2 or 3 seconds

Comment: @DIlshod It feels to me that you are doing an integration test and not unit test. It is OK for integration tests to run slow, since that you shouldn't have a lot of them. I think you should read about the Test Pyramid, [Martin Fowler wrote a good article about it](https://martinfowler.com/articles/practical-test-pyramid.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you would really have to `TestInitialize` runs before each test. You could use `ClassInitialize` to run test initialization for class only once.

**BUT**

From what I'm seeing your performance issue is caused by desing and architecutre of your application where you are breaking single responsibility principle. Creating static database entity or sharing it across test is not a solution it is only creating more technical debt. Once you share anything across test it has to be maintained acorss test AND by definition unit test ***SHOULD*** run separately and independently to allow testing each scenarion with fresh data.

You shouldn't be creating database models that depend on `MainContext`. Should single `User` really know how many `Users` there are in the database? If not then please create separate repository that will have `MainContext` injected and method `GetUsersCount()` and unit test that with InMemoryDatabase by adding few users calling specific implementation and checking if correct number of users has been added, like following:

```
public interface IUsersRepository
    {
        int GetUsersCount();
    }

    public class UsersRepository : IUsersRepository
    {
        private readonly EntityFrameworkContext _context;

        public UsersRepository(EntityFrameworkContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public int GetUsersCount()
        {
            return _context.Users.Count();
        }
    }
```

Later only methods that are really using context should be tested with`InMemoryDatabase` and for methods that are making use of IUserRepository each specific method should be mocked since it is tested separatly.

Comment: Maybe I couldn't reproduce well, but as you said 'by definition unit test SHOULD run separately and independently to allow testing each scenario with fresh data.'  I'm trying do not violate this "rule", but in my case user is creating by "structure" After creating user UserContact should be created, but in some tests I don't need UserContact.

Comment: As you see in ContactList_Test I need to create UserContact. 
 @Pranay Rana suggested to build special object for each test ( this way won't violate "rule"), but it's complex. Because whe I create ContactList_Test I didn't know that it will be fail. I found this when I was debuging test. That's why I want to create one Object by logic and use it in each test

Comment: In that case you should be creating one single test to validate if the objects are created correctly, And if you need this objects as readonly for other test you could use seeds. Could you provide in update to your comment your data models?

Comment: How can I create test for validating creating object and why I need this?

Comment: My guess would be that your method is failing becuase you are not initializing `UserContact.ContactsList` could you please provide in update `Contact` model?

Comment: Method failing because UserContact is not initializing.  ContactsList is initialized. I added Contact model.

Answer (score 0):

TestInitialize and TestCleanup are ran before and after each test, this is to ensure that no tests are coupled.

If you want to run methods before and after ALL tests only once, decorate relevant methods with the ClassInitialize and ClassCleanup attributes.

You can use the following additional attributes as you write your tests:

Sample code-

```js
// Use ClassInitialize to run code before running the first test in the class
[ClassInitialize()]
public static void MyClassInitialize(TestContext testContext) { }

// Use ClassCleanup to run code after all tests in a class have run
[ClassCleanup()]
public static void MyClassCleanup() { }

// Use TestInitialize to run code before running each test 
[TestInitialize()]
public void MyTestInitialize() { }

// Use TestCleanup to run code after each test has run
[TestCleanup()]
public void MyTestCleanup() { }
```

Basically you can have your SetEntity method in your ClassIntialize method
Hope it helps.